# How to handle video orientation from mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, video, orientation, video-processing

I have a server component that processes video uploads for a web/iOS/Android application.

However I am running into a problem handling the video orientation. Is there a good way to solve this? I have a tool MediaInfo that rips the meta data out of the device but this is what i am encountering

iOS

- the portrait is correct 90 or 270
- the landscape is crazy. if you hold the device with the button to the left, it reports 0 for the front camera and 180 for the back

Android

- here the situation is reversed the landscape is correct both front and back camera
- the portrait is 90 or 270 depending on if you are using the front or back camera
- furthermore some devices like Motorola Droids and Evo4G dont record the meta data at all

has anyone seen a clean solution for this?

Comment: Is your issue within the ripped meta data, or within the Andriod or iOS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clean solution for android devices that do not report the orientation.

For all the other orientations, I had overly complicated it in my mind.  The flip between front and back means the angles are correct if rotated clockwise